# Firebase Auth, how to return data (cred) inside Then block

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a issue, i'm trying to write my own firebase fonctions using firebase code. The thing is im using react and i need to retrive data from THEN method and returning doesnt work

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

You must return the base async function. So, put the `return` keyword before `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use promises. This will return the value of the user after the function is ready.

Good luck!

```js
const auth_connectedUser = (auth, email, password) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user)
        return resolve(user)
      }).catch(err => {
        return reject(new Error(err))
      })
  })
}



const authUser = await auth_connectedUser(auth, email, password)
```

Comment: Actually you don't need wrap the new promise. Because `signInWithEmailAndPassword` already returning promise.